# UITableViewCell duplication after UILabel text edit

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, uilabel

I have a `UITabelViewCell` used for showing active chats with contacts.

There is a Label showing the amount of unread messages per contact, information is drawn from Firebase.

When a chat is opened, the `UILabel` that shows the number of unread messages should disappear. Once it does, though, it just creates another cell, like in this picture :

[image: Before opening chat]

Then I click the chat, the chat is opened, then I click the "back" navigation item, and this shows:

[image: After navigating back to TableView]

This is my class:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class MessagesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{

    private var chats = [PrivateChatLiteObject]()

    @IBOutlet weak var ChatsTableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ChatsTableView.dataSource = self
        ChatsTableView.delegate = self
        self.view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        populateActiveChats()
    }

    private func populateActiveChats()
    {
        let loggedOnUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let ref = Constants.refs.databaseChatsLite.child(loggedOnUserID!)

            // Retrieve the products and listen for changes
        ref.observe(.value, with:
                { (snapshot) in

                    for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
                    {
                        // Code to execute when new product is added

                        let chatValueDictionary = child.value as? NSDictionary
                        self.AddChatToCollections(chatAsDictionary: chatValueDictionary, contactID: child.key)
                        self.DispatchQueueFunc()

                    }
            })
    }

    func AddChatToCollections(chatAsDictionary: NSDictionary!, contactID: String)
    {
        let contactName = chatAsDictionary["userName"] as! String
        //let contactImg = chatAsDictionary["userImageStr"] as? String
        //let lastMsg = chatAsDictionary["lastMessage"] as! String
        let newMsgs = chatAsDictionary["newMessage"] as! Int


        let chatToAdd = PrivateChatLiteObject(chattingWith: contactName, ContactID: contactID, unreadMessages: newMsgs, LastMSG: "")

        chats.append(chatToAdd)
    }

    func DispatchQueueFunc()
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                self.ChatsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return chats.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = ChatsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "chat_room_cell", for: indexPath) as! PrivateChatUITableViewCell

        //cell.ContactImageView = UIImageView.loadImageUsingUrlString(contactImg)
        let index = indexPath.row
        cell.ContactName.text = chats[index].GetContactName()

        cell.ContactID = chats[index].GetContactID()

        let unreadMSGs = chats[index].GetUnreadMessagesNumber()

        if unreadMSGs == 0
        {
            cell.NewNotificationsNum.isHidden = true
        }
        else
        {
            cell.NewNotificationsNum.isHidden = false
            let stringNotifications = String(unreadMSGs)
            cell.NewNotificationsNum.text = stringNotifications
        }

        return cell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {

        chatIndexToLoad = indexPath.row
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue_to_chatroom", sender: self)
    }

    var chatIndexToLoad: Int = -1

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if (segue.identifier == "segue_to_chatroom")
        {
            let destination = segue.destination as! PrivateChatViewController
            destination.senderId = Constants.refs.currentUserInformation!.uid
            //destination.senderDisplayName = Constants.refs.currentUserInformation?.displayName
            destination.contactDisplayName = chats[chatIndexToLoad].GetContactName()
            destination.contactID = chats[chatIndexToLoad].GetContactID()

        }
    }

}
```

I guess it has to do something with reading from Firebase firing up whenever there's a change inside a node, and re-adding the same node. I need a way to actually fire up the reading from Firebase only when a new node is added. I tried using `.childAdded` but that didn't work. Does anyone know how to solve this ?

Only thing I can think about is whenever adding an item to collection, check if chat with same contact ID doesn't exist yet, but that is bad for performance.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be an reuse issue. I think it's because you always append the contents and not replace the value if it's already there in `self.ContactNames`.

Comment: Side notes: Please do not name your var and methods starting with an uppercase that's for Classes name. Also, You should use ONE array, because `ContactNames` `NewMsgs` and `ContactIDs` are linked.

Comment: I wanted to make ONE array of "Chats", but for that I have to create a chat instance, and a chat instance has properties inside it I don't want to instantiate here. Any suggestions on how to improve this ?

Comment: "I don't want to instantiate here" WHY? Simply WHY? You can create your own custom object that have theses 3 properties, or badly use a Dict to hold them.

Comment: A chat instance holds all related messages. I don't want them to be loaded in this screen, as it's not the place for it to be done, but only after a chat has been loaded

Comment: You can create a different object that can have only theses 3 properties.

Comment: Yeah I was just thinking about it now. I'll try this and see how it goes

Comment: I edited my code :)

Comment: You are still doing `chats.append(chatToAdd)`. You should check before hand if `chats` has it. So I'd do in pseudo code `if let chat = chats.first(where: $0.GetContactID == dictionaryToAdd["contactID"]) { //Then it's already there, we need to replace its unreadmessage value} else {//It's not there, we append chats.append(chatToAdd)}`

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know how I can get the Nth element of a dictionary? I didn't seem to find a working answer. I need this because the dictionary needs to be sorted somehow in order for me to populate the TableView in "CellForIndexAt"

Comment: There is no "nth" element in a dictionary because there is no order. Use an Array instead.

Comment: I know, but using an array I am losing the ability to check if a key already exists, and then I have to iterate on the whole collection again. I read there was a method "startIndex.advancedBy" but it doesn't seem to work any longer. A solution I thought about was having both dictionary and array but I am trying to avoid another collection now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not exactly know what you are asking for, but I can share my current code which works if you would like, below. Furthermore, make sure to attach your UITableView to your ViewController as a delegate and a datasource and add this to your view controller class:

```
class NearbyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var nearbyTableView: UITableView!
var myList: [String] = []
var handle:DatabaseHandle?
var ref:DatabaseReference?






func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    var (cellName) = myList[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = cellName

    return cell

}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    var (cellName) = myList[indexPath.row]

    print("row\(indexPath.row)")
    print("name: \(cellName)")


}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()






    ref = Database.database().reference()
    handle = ref?.child("list").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let item = snapshot.value as? String
        {
            self.myList.append(item)
            self.nearbyTableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are querying for some data in FirebaseDatabase instead of using

```
ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

             //your implementation
    })
```

try using

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

             //your implementation
})
```

I noticed this strange behaviour of FirebaseDatabase, when I was using it in one of my projects. `ref.observe` was called several times and led to unexpected results, whereas `ref.observeSingleEvent` did its job well enough.